# Editing files stored on ftp in locally installed application at client from browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ftp, file-sharing

I need a solution to a problem. Although I found many solution to the problem. My client is not accepting the found solutions for security reasons.

I am having few documents stored on my FTP server and I want to give access those documents to users, from browser, using a web application, developed using angularjs and ASP.NET MVC 5, Which will open WinWord.exe at client (user's end) and when user hits save button in WinWord.exe it will upload the file back to ftp server.

I know that we can not run any exe using javascript at client.

WebDAV is another solution but some how my client did not accept solution for WebDAV, my client did not accept solution for going with any third party online editor as google Drive, word online.

Comment: "My client is not accepting the found solutions for security reasons." … and yet they are happy with the idea of giving people write access to their FTP server.

Comment: @Quentin Yes thats the irony but I need the solution to it with those conditions

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't one.

Comment: @Quentin I know its hard but I am trying every possible way to find solution to the problem. Anyways thanks for your precious time. any further suggestions are always welcome

Comment: Even though I'm not a fan, a frequently used answer to that problem is called SharePoint.

Comment: Or see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290142 "How to open documents from FTP site and save documents to FTP site with Office programs."